# How to highlight cursor line number without cursor line?

Tags: highlight, cursorline

I want the cursor line number to have a different color than the rest of numbers when `cursorline` is disabled.

The highlight `CursorLineNR` is only active when `set cursorline` is set. I could do `set cursorline` followed by `hi clear CursorLine` with `hi CursorLineNR`, however I *want* `cursorline` to be visible when sit is set and not visible when it is not set, and still have the cursor line number have a different color.

With `set cursorline` + `hi CursorLineNr guifg=#af00af`, the line number `197` is purple:

[image]

But when followed by `set nocursorline` the number `197` is gray as rest of numbers like below.

[image]

I want the `197` number to *always* be purple `guifg=#af00af`, even after `set nocursorline`. Is this anyhow possible?

I.e. compare:

```
vim -u NONE -c 'hi CursorLineNr guibg=#ff0000 ctermbg=red' -c 'set number relativenumber' -c 'exe "normal i\<cr>- should be red\<cr>\<up>\<esc>"' -c 'set nocursorline'
```

versus the same command line, but change `nocursorline` on last argument to `cursorline` and compare. The above command when run with `neovim` makes the number line in red in both cases.

Comment: `CursorLineNr Like LineNr when 'cursorline' is set and 'cursorlineopt' is
  set to "number" or "both", or 'relativenumber' is set, for
  the cursor line.
`--should be used when `rnu` is set no matter what? Having said that, my vim does what yours does. Perhaps a bug? Or perhaps the wordings means ('cul') & ('cursorlineopt' | 'rnu')

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need these three lines:

```
hi CursorLineNr guifg=#af00af
set cursorline
set cursorlineopt=number
```

The last line removes the highlighting of the cursor line even if `cursorline` is set and only highlights the cursor line number.

Comment: Very nice, note, this needs at least 8.1.2019 I believe

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Yes, and 8.1.2155 if it's to be used in a terminal window (which is probably not the case here).